# Meaning of んな after verb in て form

Tags: grammar, て-form

> 関口やナベちゃんに「そんなとこ、ボッと立っ**てんな**よ」と言われたことを思いだし、情けなさそうにうなずいた。
>   He recalled being told by 関口やナベ that ??? and bowed his head miserably.

To be honest, I'm stuck on everything in the quotes (something about blushing?) but, in particular I'm puzzled about the んな part in bold after the te-form verb. I'm guessing it's a contraction of たってのな but I've never seen that before either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a contraction of ～ているな. The な here means 'don't', as a negative imperative. 「ボッと立ってんなよ」 means 「ボッと立っているなよ」 'Don't just stand there dazed.'

Comment: A negative imperative with ～ている? Is it possible at all?

Comment: @macraf I don't see why it shouldn't be, since you get 待っていろ and the like.